# How can I write a jQuery conditional in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

I did this and worked fine:

```
c:if test="${usuario.temEsteAcesso('spg027')}" >
 <td class="alignCenter">
  <a onclick="clicaLancamento();" class="bt" id="btnLancamentos">
   <span>Lançamentos</span>
  </a>
</c:if>
```

But now I want to call usuario again in a JavaScript init function and knows if an attributte from usuario is true or false. I tried this, but not worked:

```
if(jQuery("#usuario").sucursal()){
    console.log("Teste sucursal.");
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: an boolean attribute from usuario, usuario is a bean

Comment: What does `c:if test=` stand for? And `${...}` syntax is supported by what? I guess you forgot to tag at least one more framework or tool.

Comment: i'm using spring  mvc too in my code

Comment: Then please tag it. People use tags to find interesting questions, and also to filter out uninteresting ones.

Answer (score 0):

in your `.js` file you can call **jQuery** like this, and using this way you don't need to assign your **JS** funcion to any element, you can intercept any modification in the **DOM**.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#usuario").on('click', function(){
        var sucursal = $("#usuario").val();

        // Check your property
        if(...){

            //Then do something
        }
    });

});
```

regards,